# django not serving angular js files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django

i am trying to use django with angular js but it throws error while trying to include the angular js files

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/libs/angular.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/modules/app.module.js' %}"></script>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/modules/app.config.js' %}"></script>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/modules/blog-list.module.js' %}"></script>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/controllers/blog-list.js' %}"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name">
        <p>hi , {{name}}</p>

        <div ng-controller="BlogListController">
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>
            <button ng-click="someTest()">click</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is the settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for trueguild project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
import datetime
from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
#root of project

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'csqwlmc8s55o($rt6ozh7u+ui9zb-et00w$d90j8$^!nvj41_r'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.MyUser'
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'accounts.UserProfile'



INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #django app
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #third party apps
    'mptt',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'endless_pagination',
    'rest_framework',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.amazon',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.bitbucket',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.dropbox',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.github',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.instagram',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin_oauth2',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.stackexchange',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.tumblr',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
    #my apps
    'products' ,
    'likes' ,
    'accounts',
    'analytics',
    'store' ,
    'billing',
    'carts' ,
    'orders' ,
    'notifications',
    'sellers',
    'dataentry',
    'management',
    'coupons',
    'sales',
    # 'Transactions',
)

SITE_ID = 1
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
    {'facebook':
       {'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        'SCOPE': ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_friends'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'FIELDS': [
            'id',
            'email',
            'name',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'verified',
            'locale',
            'timezone',
            'link',
            'gender',
            'updated_time'],
        'EXCHANGE_TOKEN': True,
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False,
        'VERSION': 'v2.4'}}


ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username_email' 
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 10 
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = 'Subject is'
ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = 'http'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET =True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_EMAIL_FIELD = 'email' 
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH = 4
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_BLACKLIST = []
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_INPUT_RENDER_VALUE = False
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH =6
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION = True
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'accounts.forms.SignupForm'


MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',

)


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.core.context_processors.request',

            ],
        },
    },
]


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

)

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'trueguild.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases
#django.db.backends.mysql

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql_cymysql', 
        'NAME': 'trueguild',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# STATICFILES_DIRS = (
#     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_files"),
#     #os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_in_env"),
#     #'/var/www/static/',
# )

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media_root")


ROOT_URLCONF = 'trueguild.urls'

#Crispy FORM TAGs SETTINGS
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'


#DJANGO REGISTRATION REDUX SETTINGS
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN = True


TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),)



SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False

INTERNAL_IPS = '139.59.17.17'

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PATCH_SETTINGS = False

WHOOSH_INDEX = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'whoosh')

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.whoosh_backend.WhooshEngine',
        'PATH': WHOOSH_INDEX ,
    },
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSIONS_CLASSES' : {
     'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    },
}


JWT_AUTH = {
 "JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER" : "trueguild.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler",
 "JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA" : datetime.timedelta(seconds=30000),
 "JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH" : True
}

SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER ="orders.adapters.MySocialAccountAdapter"
```

> Django server is throwing 404 error Although the file is present at
>   the location

How can i server angular js files .Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) Did you just paste your settings file without removing your email and password? May want to delete this question and try again...or change your password. 2) Can you share your directory structure - where are the .js files kept? 3) Do you have other static files that are being served correctly?

Comment: Also looks like you have Braintree credentials, your server IP, and database login info in the settings file.

Comment: thats just a temp password